# Tensorflow Estimator warning

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using Tensorflow 1.2 I'm getting this warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/linear.py:565: calling predict (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with x is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
Instructions for updating:
Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
Example conversion:
  est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

data = pd.read_csv('data/titanic.csv')
random.seed(42)

_N_CLASSES = 2
_LEARNING_RATE = 0.05
_TRAIN_STEPS = 200

CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ['Age', 'SibSp', 'Fare']
LABEL_COLUMN = 'Survived'

# Data collection
y, X = data[LABEL_COLUMN], data[CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS].fillna(0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Feature columns. Get Numerical values
feature_columns = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X_train)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=_LEARNING_RATE)

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(n_classes=_N_CLASSES,
                                               feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                               optimizer=optimizer)

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, steps=100)
print accuracy_score(y_test, classifier.predict(X_test, as_iterable=False))
```

I tried to replace the classifier.fit but I get this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:float64 is not supported by many models, consider casting to float32.
    WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /var/folders/p2/jh8vcbv51ks2gzvfx3dw1bd000_wjb/T/tmp9wOYQs
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/Development/google/python/machine_learning/deep_learning_with_python/binary_classification/titanic/titanic_0.py", line 42, in <module>
        classifier.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=_TRAIN_STEPS)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 289, in new_func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 455, in fit
        loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 955, in _train_model
        model_fn_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1162, in _get_train_ops
        return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1133, in _call_model_fn
        model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/linear.py", line 164, in _linear_model_fn
        scope=scope)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py", line 486, in weighted_sum_from_feature_columns
        transformed_tensor = transformer.transform(column)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py", line 838, in transform
        feature_column.insert_transformed_feature(self._columns_to_tensors)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py", line 1789, in insert_transformed_feature
        input_tensor = self._normalized_input_tensor(columns_to_tensors[self.name])
    KeyError: ''
```

This is the new code, where I pass a function

> input_fn

returning features and labels according to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py) example.

```
# TF model
def make_input_fn(features, target):
    def input_fn():
        feature_cols = {k: tf.constant(features[k].values) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
        feature_dict = dict(feature_cols)
        label = tf.constant(target.values)
        return feature_dict, label
    return input_fn


input_fn = make_input_fn(X_train, y_train)
classifier.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=_TRAIN_STEPS)
```

**Debugging**

```
print type(y_train)
print type(feature_cols)
print type(feature_dict)
print type(y_train.values)
print feature_dict
print label

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
{'Fare': <tf.Tensor 'Const_2:0' shape=(712,) dtype=float64>, 'Age': <tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=(712,) dtype=float64>, 'SibSp': <tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=(712,) dtype=int64>}
Tensor("Const_3:0", shape=(712,), dtype=int64)
```